# Segmentation fault 11 in c after execution

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I don't understand why I'm getting segmentation fault in the code this simple and straight forward, please help. I checked the code again and again but i couldn't figure it out.
The whole point of the code is to check whether I can write an Insert method without returning pointer to node.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct BSTNode
{
        int data;
        struct BSTNode *left;
        struct BSTNode *right;
};

struct BST
{
        struct BSTNode *root;
};

struct BST *CreateBST(void);
void Insert(struct BSTNode *root,int data);

int main(void)
{
        struct BST *tree = CreateBST();
        int a[6]= {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
                Insert(tree->root,a[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}

struct BST *CreateBST(void)
{
        return NULL;
}

void Insert(struct BSTNode *root,int data)
{
        if(root == NULL)
        {
                struct BSTNode *new_node = (struct BSTNode *) malloc (sizeof(struct BSTNode));
                if(!new_node)
                {
                        printf("Memory Error");
                        return;
                }
                new_node->data = data;
                new_node->left = NULL;
                new_node->right= NULL;
                root = new_node;
        }
        else if(data<= root->data)
                Insert(root->left,data);
        else if(data>root->data)
            Insert(root->right,data);
    return;
}
```

Comment: If `root` is null, for instance because you called it via `Insert(root->left,data);`, and you allocate a new root, will this be stored back into `root->left` in the previous call on the callstack?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Then learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). On Linux, using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) should also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call the function `CreateBST` which returns `NULL`. Then you try to dereference this `NULL` pointer by doing `tree->root`. This will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and your crash.

---

There are also other problems with your program, for example (if you fix the above problem) you pass `tree->root` *by value* to `Insert`, which means that inside the `Insert` function `root` is a copy, and changing the copy will not change the original.

Answer (score -3):

Segmantation fault error occurrs when a program try to access to a memory zone that is not of its competence. Try to reboot,this will probabily fix the error.

Comment: rebooting hardly ever fixes a segfault. The OP is dereferencing a NULL pointer, rebooting can't magically fix bad code